# Cycles- eyes are rendered multicolored, bright pink and blue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

***Note-** I'm a noob at Blender.  I apologize in advance for my noobishness, and please explain things thoroughly for me.

This is a model I have imported from MakeHuman (the official release, not nightly), and rendered in Cycles.  I have followed a tutorial online to procure a solution to the "all-black-eye" problem, and this is my result. I haven't created anything else for the eyes to reflect. 
   [image: crazy eyes]

Below are my nodes.  The image texture window on the top is my Alpha, the middle is the image texture, and the bottom is my texture_ref.  The texture_ref file I made on my own (and probably incorrectly) by copying the original image, using Gimp to change it to grayscale, and then exporting it as a jpg. This doesn't seem to be the problem, as I've disconnected it entirely and the eyes were still all rainbow, but I thought I should include that anyway.

[image]

I have no idea what is going on.

**Edit-** Below I've uploaded my textures.  The first is my texture.ref, the second my Alpha, and the third is my texture.

[image: Alpha]
[image: texture.ref]

[image: image texture]

Comment: They could be reflections of the environment, or something in the textures.. Is it possible you could upload the .blend with textures for closer inspection?

Comment: I recommend you enable the Node Wrangler addon (installed by default) and ctrl+shift+click each node starting from the left to see what effect they have - then you'll see at which point the problem is.

Comment: That's normal, the UVs aren't being used as color information in your node setup, they are being used to define the mapping for your textures. So that shouldn't have anything to do with it..

Comment: @gandalf3 Is it?  I'll edit it back, then.  Sorry, my inner noob is showing.

Comment: @AbbyPartridge I don't see anything wrong in the screenshot, and it will be hard to troubleshoot without a .blend.. Is it possible you could at least upload a partial .blend with just the objects/materials/textures necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I'm in the process.

Comment: I've remade your material here and it seems to be working fine for me.. I suspect some kind of reflection of the environment or something.

Comment: @gandalf3 I haven't created an environment...

Comment: @AbbyPartridge That's really odd then.. Perhaps there is something about your eye object that's causing this? I can't think what it might be..

Comment: @gandalf3 If I'm in material view and I rotate the view so that I'm inside the skull and can see the inside of the eyeballs, they look normal...it's like they're inside out or something.

Comment: @AbbyPartridge Are the normals facing outwards? Try selecting the eyes in edit mode and pressing Ctrl N

Comment: @gandalf3 There was no effect

Comment: @Pachysandra This is really quite odd.. I'm sorry, but without a .blend of at least the eye I don't think there is much I can do.